# Gunicorn 19.x no longer shows [INFO] when started from the terminal (in dev environment)

Tags: python, gunicorn

Gunicorn 19.x no longer shows [INFO] when started from the terminal (in dev environment). So the question is...is this the new behavior or did I install/configure something incorrectly? Perhaps this a flag now? Or how do I get it back, if possible? (From what I can tell, gunicorn works correctly)

Pictures are worth a thousand words:

### Gunicorn 18.0 [image: Gunicorn 18.0]

### Gunicorn 19.1 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [FAQ: Why I don’t see any logs in the console?](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/faq.html#why-i-don-t-see-any-logs-in-the-console)

> Since the version R19, Gunicorn doesn’t log by default in the console.
>   To watch the logs in the console you now need to use the option
>   `--log-file=-`.